Should a function be placed inside or outside the build method in Flutter? Does it affect performance or clean code practices?
I'm working on a Flutter app and wondering about best practices related to placing functions inside or outside the build method.
For example, I have two versions of a simple onPressed function. One is defined inside the build method:
class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) { 
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Inside Build')),
      body: Center(
        child: ElevatedButton(
          onPressed:() {
             //... do something
          },
          child: Text('Press Me'),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

And another one where the function is placed outside the build method:
class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {

  void _showMessage(BuildContext context) {
    //... do something
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Outside Build')),
      body: Center(
        child: ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: () => _showMessage(context),
          child: Text('Press Me'),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

My Questions:

Is there any performance difference between defining a function inside or outside the build method?
From a clean code perspective, which approach is preferable?
Are there any cases where defining a function inside or outside the build method is a better choice?


I’d recommend keeping functions outside the build method. It keeps your code cleaner and avoids recreating the function every time the widget rebuilds, which is better for performance. If it’s a simple one-liner, defining it inside is fine, but for anything more, it's best to separate the logic.
using outside:

Better for performance in cases where the widget is rebuilt
frequently. This approach is recommended when the function contains
more complex logic, is used in multiple places, or needs to access
class-level state.

using inside:

For very simple, one-off functions, defining them inside the build
method can be convenient.
Keeps everything in one place, which might
be preferable for very small widgets.

